# What is the jQuery syntax to only select values in the dropdown list of checkboxes which are checked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

HI,
The scenario is I want to select values of all the checkboxes checked in a dropdown list with class name .product-dropdown, I tried following combonations but nothing has worked -

```
$(".product-dropdown li").each("input[type='checkbox']:checked", function(e){
        var cmd = $(this).val();
        addToTextBox(cmd);
});

$(".product-dropdown li input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(e){
        var cmd = $(this).val();
        addToTextBox(cmd);
});

$(".product-dropdown input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(e){
        var cmd = $(this).val();
        addToTextBox(cmd);
});
```

I am new to jQuery, and not familiar with the syntax, I want to select the values from each checkbox checked in the dropdown of checkboxes and append it to the contents of a checkbox

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the jQuery documentation, [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) is correct.

I tried with :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

and it worked.

Are you sure the class is `.product-dropdown` and the path is correct ? (`.product-dropdown input`)

You can also try to debug if the problem isn't into `addToTextBox`. It could be a reason why your code isn't executed.

Comment: I think even .size()>0 condition would also work. Though I have gone ahead with .lenth
@cx42net: Thanks :)